# Geometry package not working on my other pages

Tags: header-footer, packages, margins, page-breaking, geometry

I am having problems with the geometry package.
The pre-set package is only working on my first page, and not on the second.

The code in the beginning is as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage[showframe=true,left=0.41in, top=0.6in, total={6.2in,11in}]{geometry}
```

I cannot seem to find a workaround, I tried adjusting the margins on the new page manually and I also tried the \newgeometry and \restoregeometry prompts, but nothing worked.

This is how it looks at the moment.
The top page is how I want it (like the measures in the package); the second page is what I want to fix.

[image]

Code at the second page:

```
\newpage
    \extrawidth{-0.35in}
    \pointsdroppedatright
    \question[1/1/1] Sigmund säger självsäkert att han kan bevisa att 1 = 0, och ställer upp följande bevis:
    \[a=b\ \Leftrightarrow\ a-b=0\ \Leftrightarrow\ \frac{a-b}{a-b}=\frac{0}{a-b}\ \Leftrightarrow\ 1=0 \]
    Förklara vad Sigmund har gjort för fel och var hans logiska resonemang brister. 
    \droppoints

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The geometry looks right, the problem is how that `(1/1/1)` was inserted there. Show more code to us, otherwise is hard to help.

Comment: I put some more code from the second page.
The \droppoints are working fine, they seem to be positioned the same on both pages, but it's the main text that is unmatching.

Comment: Welcome to TeX - LaTeX! [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: I managed to solve it, the \extrawidth{-0.35in} was not affecting the second page, so I removed both commands from both pages, which adjusted left margin on both pages according to measures in geometry package.